# Add custom font to the React Native Application - Version > 0.60

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am using React Native (V-0.64).
I used the method of downloading and adding the custom font in the assets folder and creating a `react-native.config.js` file and export the link from there. But I keep getting the following error when I run the app on the device.
COdes in the file

```
module.exports = {
  assets: ['./assets/fonts'],
};
```

Then run the `npx react-native link` to link the assets into the android and iOS files. But I keep getting the following error in the lines and do not get the font changes in the Text

```
fontFamily "VeganStylePersonalUse-5Y58" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.
at node_modules/expo-font/build/Font.js:27:16 in processFontFamily
at [native code]:null in commitRootImpl
at [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
at [native code]:null in forEach
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpReactRefresh.js:43:6 in Refresh.performReactRefresh
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I tried lots of things but did not work. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To `loadFonts` which I do in all my project is create a folder called `hooks` where your `App.js` is located

Then, Install `expo-app-loading` & `expo-font`

Then inside `hooks` folder create a file called `useFonts.js`

Inside `useFonts.js` write like this

```
import * as Font from "expo-font";

export default useFonts = async () => {
   await Font.loadAsync({
      "Montserrat-Bold": require("../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf"),
    });
};.
```

Now in your `App.js` write like this

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';

export default function App() {
  const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);

  const LoadFonts = async () => {
    await useFonts();
  };

  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFonts}
        onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}
        onError={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }

  return <View styles={styles.container}>{/* Code Here */}</View>;
}
```

Comment: I'm facing this error:
None of these files exist:
  * SFUIText-Light.ttf
  * assets/fonts/sf-ui-text/SFUIText-Light.ttf/index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.svg|.native.svg|.svg)