# React Native Expo - Custom Fonts Not Loading With Font.loadAsync

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, fonts, expo

I'm up to date on the latest Expo version but for some reason, I can not get a simple custom font going. Here is a fresh project I set up attempting to get a custom font installed.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

const fetchFonts = () =>
  Font.loadAsync({
    'Inter-Black': require('./assets/fonts/Inter-Black.otf'),
  });

export default (props) => {
  const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (!dataLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => setDataLoaded(true)}
        onError={(err) => console.log(err)}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter-Black', fontSize: 40 }}>
        Inter Black
      </Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>Platform Default</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

This is what I get in the console:

```
fontFamily "Inter-Black" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.
at node_modules/expo-font/build/Font.js:27:16 in processFontFamily
at [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
at [native code]:null in dispatchAction
at App.js:19:37 in AppLoading.props.onFinish
at node_modules/expo-app-loading/build/AppLoading.js:41:12 in startLoadingAppResourcesAsync
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

Comment: Does this solve your issue?
[How to load custom fonts with the useFonts hook in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77172404)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to await the loading fucntion

```js
const fetchFonts = async () =>
  await Font.loadAsync({
    'Inter-Black': require('./assets/fonts/Inter-Black.otf'),
  });
```

Also, instead of this, try creating a custom hook to Load fonts. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68432827/13170636) answer.

You can do it somenthing like this

Create a folder called `hooks` where your `App.js` is located. Then inside `hooks` folder create a file called `useFonts.js`

Inside `useFonts.js` write like this

```js
import * as Font from "expo-font";
 
export default useFonts = async () =>
  await Font.loadAsync({
    'Inter-Black': require('./assets/fonts/Inter-Black.otf'),
  });
```

Now in your `App.js` write like this

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';

export default function App() {
  const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);

  const LoadFonts = async () => {
    await useFonts();
  };

  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFonts}
        onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}
        onError={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }

  return <View styles={styles.container}>{/* Code Here */}</View>;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting : Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

because of `onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}`,

if I remove `SetIsReady(true)` (eg: `onFinish={() => {}` ) from the call the error will not be invoked, but the app will not load either! 

how resolve it?

Comment: Yes, untill you not set the state `IsReady` to true, it will show you the `AppLoading` component, and hence, you app is not loading. [Here's](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/loading-custom-fonts) a snack that performs font-loading operation. Hope this helps.

Comment: By the way, I created a new project, and the code you suggested, works fine. However, by introducing a new useState const the same error will be invoked!

 Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

Comment: Finally, I found the source of the issue!  the problem was that i had some `useState` and `useRef` constants below this code : 

`if (!IsReady) { return ( <AppLoading startAsync={LoadFonts} .../>);}`

By simply moving my `useState` and `useRef`  constants above this code now the code working perfectly fine.

I guess the issue was those hooks weren’t accessible in the first render, but once IsReady is true they became accessible, thus, the error:  `Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render`

Comment: I'm facing this error:
```js
None of these files exist:
  * SFUIText-Light.ttf
  * assets/fonts/sf-ui-text/SFUIText-Light.ttf/index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.svg|.native.svg|.svg)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Add font resource to project folder exp assets/fonts
2. create variable fonts exp customFonts
3. Import on App.js like this

   ```
   import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
   import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
   let customFonts = {
     'Poppins-Black': require('./assets/fonts/Poppins-Black.ttf')
   };

   const App = () => {
     const [isLoaded] = useFonts(customFonts);
     if (!isLoaded) {
       return <AppLoading />;
     }
       return <RootApp />;
   }
   ```