# Font.loadAsync does not load fonts and because of this shows splash

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

the loading of fonts has not been working for several days and I cannot find the reason, and there is something else wrong with expo go, it takes a very long time to load, and for some reason after exp publish the application is not updated in any way, does anyone know the reason?
**during development (6 months) there were no problems, but two days ago for some reason the fonts broke and I can't find the reason**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

if you remove the loading of fonts, then the application is loaded.

**"expo-cli": "4.11.0",

"expo": "~40.0.0",

"expo-app-loading": "^1.0.1",

"react": "16.13.1",

"react-dom": "16.13.1",

"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",**

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569844/react-native-expo-custom-fonts-not-loading-with-font-loadasync/68570172#68570172) help?

Comment: @Kartikey the problem is not that it does not wait for loading and because of this an error is displayed that the fonts were not loaded, but somewhere in the code they are used, but that the fonts are not loaded at all, Font.loadAsync does not load them

Comment: @Kartikey "expo-app-loading": "^1.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

*In my case, when using expo go, I noticed that it takes a long time to load with AppLoading if the clocks(of my phone and my computer) are not in sync.

*IF it helps I'll show you How I load Fonts in my app, I am using currently using:

**"expo": "^41.0.0",**

**"expo-app-loading": "^1.1.2",**

**"expo-font": "~9.1.0",**

**"react": "16.13.1",**

**"react-dom": "16.13.1",**

**"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",**

```
 const fetchFonts = async () => {
     return await Font.loadAsync({
        'gotham-narrow-black':{
             uri: require('./assets/fonts/gotham/GothamNarrow-Black.otf'),
             display: Font.FontDisplay.FALLBACK
        },
        'gotham-narrow-book':{
             uri: require('./assets/fonts/gotham/GothamNarrow-Book.otf'),
             display: Font.FontDisplay.FALLBACK
        },
        'gotham-ultra':{
             uri: require('./assets/fonts/gotham/Gotham-Ultra.otf'),
             display: Font.FontDisplay.FALLBACK
        },
       'gotham-light':{
             uri: require('./assets/fonts/gotham/GothamLight.otf'),
             display: Font.FontDisplay.FALLBACK
        },
       'gotham-book':{
             uri: require('./assets/fonts/gotham/Gotham-Book.otf'),
             display: Font.FontDisplay.FALLBACK
        },
  })
}

export default function App() {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);
  if(!fontLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading 
      startAsync = { fetchFonts }
      onError = { console.warn }
      onFinish = { () => setFontLoaded(true) }
    />
  }
  return <MainApp />;
}
```

Comment: have you ever encountered such an error?
SSL handshake aborted: ssl = 0x92d95240: I / O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

Comment: No, I'm afraid not

Answer (score 0):

As your font is a static file you will have to change your `fontLoading` function

Change this

```js
import Helvetica from './Helvetica.ttf';

const useFonts = async () =>
  await Font.loadAsync({
    Helvetica: Helvetica, // not like this
  });
```

to this

```js
const useFonts = async () =>
  await Font.loadAsync({
    Helvetica: require('./Helvetica.ttf'), // correct location
  });
```

So in your case change your `loadFonts` function to this

```js
const loadFonts = async () =>
  await Font.loadAsync({
    montserratRegular: require('./assets/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
    montserratBold: require('./assets/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'),
    montserratSemiBold: require('./assets/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf'),
    montserratMedium: require('./assets/Montserrat-Medium.ttf'),
  });
```

Comment: have you ever encountered such an error?
SSL handshake aborted: ssl = 0x92d95240: I / O error during system call, Connection reset by peer