# expo-fonts: Cannot assign to 'useFonts' because it is a read-only property

Tags: typescript, react-native, fonts, expo, hook

**Cannot assign to 'useFonts' because it is a read-only property**

I'm using expo and trying to import a .ttf font to my react-native project (TypeScript).

I tried to create a hook "useFont" to load all fonts before open the aplication (see [React Native Expo - Custom Fonts Not Loading With Font.loadAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569844/react-native-expo-custom-fonts-not-loading-with-font-loadasync)).

At first I tried:

```js
import * as Font from "expo-font";

export default useFonts = async () =>
    await Font.loadAsync({
        'LeagueSpartan': require('../assets/fonts/LeagueSpartan.ttf'),
    });
```

and the error `Cannot find name 'useFonts'` appears.

So i tried:

```js
import * as Font from "expo-font";

export default Font.useFonts = async () =>
    await Font.loadAsync({
        'LeagueSpartan': require('../assets/fonts/LeagueSpartan.ttf'),
    });
```

and now I receiving `Cannot assign to 'useFonts' because it is a read-only property`

It feels like no one is correct actualy. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're exporting using `default`

Try:

```js
import * as Font from "expo-font";

export const useFonts = async () =>
  await Font.loadAsync({
    'LeagueSpartan': require('../assets/fonts/LeagueSpartan.ttf'),
  });
```

And then to use it just import it using

```js
import { useFonts } from './path-to-your-file';
```